# binary field, Waterline ORM

Tags: mysql, node.js, file, sails.js, waterline

I'm trying to insert a file represented by a **node JS buffer object** in a table field (**MySQL**) (type binary in **waterline js**),
 When reading it and writing it into a file, the file is corrupted, i implemented a java program that updates the line in the table containing the file,i read it and the file is perfect, the problem appears to occur when writing into the database,
 and there is no documentations about binary fields in **waterline ORM**.
How can i solve this ?
I have opened an issue on this, it's probably a bug in sails-mysql.
[The issue on github](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-mysql/issues/183)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug was corrected in the 0.10.8 version of sails-mysql.